# PHP Return Value from Controller to Ajax

Tags: php, ajax, codeigniter

I am using a MVC and I have a button that is using an AJAX call to remove an uploaded image on the site.

This is my Model:

```
public function remove_document($documentID, $documentName)
    {
        $objData = $this->objDB
            -> setStoredProc('attritionRemoveDocument')
            -> setParam('documentID', $documentID)
            -> setParam('documentName', $documentName)
            -> execStoredProc()
            -> parseXML();

        return $objData->data->response;    

    }
```

The response back from this is either `true` or `false`.

Here is my controller:

```
public function deleteFile()
    {
        // Get the documentID we are removing
        $documentID = $this->input->post('documentID');
        $documentName = $this->input->post('documentName');

        // Check if the file is even there
        if (file_exists('./uploads/'.$documentName)){

            // Remove file
            unlink('./uploads/'.$documentName);
            $removeFile = $this->submit_model->remove_document($documentID, $documentName);

            return $removeFile;

         }

   }
```

And finally, my AJAX Call:

```
$('[name=deleteDocument]').click(function() {

        var documentID = $(this).attr('documentID'),
            documentName = $(this).attr('documentName');

        //Delete the image
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: '../deleteFile',
            dataType: 'xml',
            data: {
                'documentID': documentID,
                'documentName': documentName
            },
            success: function(msg) {

                // On Success, remove the current file section
                console.log(msg);

            }

        });

    });
```

When i `echo` the `$removeFile` value in the controller, I see the `true/false` value however it never makes it to the success function of the AJAX call.

Any ideas?

Comment: Ajax can not retrieve return value of the `PHP` function. You need to use `echo` instead.

Comment: I changed it to to echo but `console.log(msg);` still doesn't display the value. Is there something else I need to add to `msg`?

Comment: your datatype attribute in the ajax call is expecting XML back from the server, which is why I answered the way I did.  Try changing it to `html`

Answer (score 0):

in Controller

if the result is true

```
echo "OK"
```

if the result is false

```
echo "NO"
```

in your View  and in success part

```
success: function(msg) {

  if(msg=="OK"){

    alert("DELETED");

   }else{
    alert("NOT deleted");
   }
```

Your controller should not return BOOL if you are using it with ajax , Your AJAX call , should control  the result by success method .